# How to get the host name and ipv4 address in Powerbuilder 2019?

Tags: powerbuilder

I would like to create a log of connections to the database with the user name, computer name, and ipv4 address, but using calls to the kernel32.dll gets me garbage characters, like 䍐䌭位剎奏. I was thinking on something along the lines of:

$computer = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
$ipcomputer = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($computer)

assuming I can get those values back to PB2019. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: The samples at Top Wiz Programming might help. https://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode.html

Comment: Nice link @Slapout. It actually contains the reason I was getting those weird characters: I missed including the ANSI at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage the function spits needs to be converted to ANSI before making any sense. Thanks to @Slapout for the link that helped me solve this.